# Shortcuts to select items in sidepanel in Nautilus?

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut, nautilus

In ubuntu nautilus, what is the shortcut to focus on the side panel (where we have 'Places', 'Devices', 'Networks' etc.) so we can navigate and select which folder to get into? I tried to find it online but it seems that nobody's mentioning it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/28234/719469 might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then you can use arrows <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate (you need to press an arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> twice after <kbd>Tab</kbd> to kind of activate it - quite a long shortcut: <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>).

---

Edit: After many trial and error, here it is: <kbd>F6</kbd>.